# Umbraco how to get nodes from winform app

Tags: wpf, winforms, umbraco

How can i get the nodes out of umbraco in a winforms app?
Basically, I want to use umbraco as dataentry, and have a winforms/wpf application visualize the data that was stored in umbraco. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do that using the Umbraco .NET APIs.  Just include the correct Umbraco dlls as references and then you can load content or media and manipulate it using the API.

See more on the API in the Documentation section on Our Umbraco:

http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/